# Why do the correct api_id and api_hash not work a second time?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Example code:

```
api_id = 'xxxx'
api_hash = 'xxxxxx'

from asyncio import run

class new_client():
    async def work(self, user_id, phone):
        from telethon import TelegramClient
        client = TelegramClient(user_id, api_id, api_hash)
        await client.connect()
        await client.send_code_request(phone)
        myself = await client.sign_in(phone, input('>>> '))
        await client.disconnect()
        del client

class c2t():
    async def work(self, user_id):
        from opentele.td import TDesktop
        from opentele.tl import TelegramClient
        from opentele.api import API, UseCurrentSession
        client_s2t = TelegramClient('{}.session'.format(user_id))  
        tdesk = await client_s2t.ToTDesktop() 
        tdesk.SaveTData(user_id)
        await client_s2t.log_out()
        del client_s2t

run(new_client().work('userid1', 'number'))
run(c2t().work('userid1'))

run(new_client().work('userid2', 'number'))
run(c2t().work('userid2'))
```

I have a working api_id and api_hash, as well as a phone number to which the codes to sign in to Telegram will be sent. I need to create two sessions with different names, which will contain this account. The first session file is created correctly, but when I try to create the second one I get an error: telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ApiIdInvalidError: The api_id/api_hash combination is invalid (caused by SendCodeRequest)

How do I get the results I want?

P.S. Sorry for the bad English, it's DeepL :)

Comment: https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/46 might be relevant.